Nodejs lru-cache - FATAL invalid size error 169224256
EDIT:
A bit of debugging shows that the problem lies in lru-cache:
public async get(key: string, fetcher: () => Promise<T>, refresh?: boolean): Promise<T | Error> {
        if(!this.usedKeys.includes(key)) {
            this.usedKeys.push(key);
        }

        const value = this.cache.get(this.namespace + "_" + key);
        if (value && !refresh) {
            return value as T;
        }
        try {
            const result = await fetcher();
            if (result instanceof Error) return result;
            console.log('caching')
            this.cache.set(this.namespace + "_" + key, result);
            console.log('cached');
            return result;
        } catch (e) {
            return e;
        }
    }

cache: LRUCache<string,any>, from lib lru-cache
It breaks after 'caching'. HOWEVER in a previous version of this application I stored same amount of rows/columns and worked well, just before it was {[p: string]: any}[] and now it is any[][] (so headers are stored in separate variable to save memory.
PREVIOUS QUESTION:
I'm getting an error when *trying to .map() exactly 235886 rows queried by node-pg:
#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# Fatal JavaScript invalid size error 169224256
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 0x7ffdf0e186e0
 1: 0xbee3e1  [node]
 2: 0x1e6b0b4 V8_Fatal(char const*, ...) [node]
 3: 0xf07f88  [node]
 4: 0x10b7452  [node]
 5: 0x10b7712  [node]
 6: 0x12c6adb v8::internal::Runtime_GrowArrayElements(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
 7: 0x17035b9  [node]
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

in:
const query = await this.pool.query(queryString,params);
if(query) {
    console.log(query.rowCount)
    this.queryDate = new Date();
    return {
        data: query.rows.map(row => Object.values(row)),
        data_headers: query.fields.map((field) => {
            return {
                column: field.name,
                datatype: PG_TYPE_MAP[field.dataTypeID] || 'text'
            }
        }),
        localized_headers: query.fields.map((field) => {
            const localized = localizedNames[field.name];
            return localized ?? field.name;
        }),
        original_length: query.rowCount
    }
}

I need to turn that object into values array because that's how my current system works - by caching it, paginating and sending to react client - and works well but for smaller tables ;)
Any ideas how to resolve it? I already set max-old-space-size to 8gigs, but the problem still occurs.

How many columns does the query return?

edited question, sounds like the problem is lru-cache.
235886 rows and around 50 columns (some string, some bool, some number)

That's quite huge. You already have all the data in an array of objects, now you're doubling it up with an array of arrays.

I don't think so, old array of objects is just transformed into array of arrays, I believe old one is deleted by GC, if not just called delete query.rows; after .map, but it didn't change anything

But the old one isn't GCed until after the new one is created. Until the function returns they're both in memory.

Yup that's right. But as said error is happening later, while caching with lru-cache. That part with object to array works, just caching causes fatal and I don't think that's lack of memory issue

Found a solution - size estimation of any[][] causes such error, but for the same dataset (or even larger, because with headers) {}[] is not. Weird, but gotta search for another solution than object-sizeof lib.
this.cache = new LRUCache({
    max: 20, ttl: 1000 * 60 * 60 /* 1h live time */, sizeCalculation: (obj) => {
        return sizeof(obj); // <---- HERE
    }, maxSize: 1.5 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024
});

